# Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task
>
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library'.
>   Unable to unzip
>   '/home/abhinavralhan/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/26.0.0-alpha1/animated-vector-drawable-26.0.0-alpha1.aar'
>   to
>   '/home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache/3640b9dd51da6db8e5ab286317dbd8fc702b33c2/output'
>   or find the cached output
>   '/home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache/3640b9dd51da6db8e5ab286317dbd8fc702b33c2/output'
>   using the build cache at '/home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache'.
>   To troubleshoot the issue or learn how to disable the build cache, go
>   to https://d.android.com/r/tools/build-cache.html.   If you are unable
>   to fix the issue, please file a bug at
>   https://d.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

### BUILD FAILED

Above is the error shown in the Gradle console. Don't mark this as duplicate as none of the existing solutions work. I've tried removing cache, downloaded a new SDK but neither of the solutions seem to work. Thanks in advance. If you need build.gradle or any other source file let me know.

Comment: have you tried to clean+rebuild? have you tried running with `--stacktrace` to get the stack trace?

Comment: Running it with --stacktrace gives me this error :  
  
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create directory /home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache  
  
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create directory /home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache  java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create directory /home/abhinavralhan/.android/build-cache

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and should work for other versions too.**

Within Android Studio goto:

```
View>Tool Windows>Terminal
```

Here, run the following command:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

After the command has executed with a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message, close Android Studio and navigate to:

```
<YOUR_PATH>/android-studio/bin
```

Here, from within the terminal, run the `studio.sh` script with **superuser priviliges(this is important)**.

```
$ sudo bash studio.sh
```

That's it. Your Gradle should build successfully now.

Comment: The problem was that it did not have su access to .android and .cache directories and it has been resolved.